# Python update multiple Postgresql records inside of loop

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to update the records inside a postgresql database am stuck. Right now I'm just cleaning each record, but later will use the same approach for machine translations of each record.

The function connects, pulls down the records, cleans them with no problem, then stops at the update statement. What am I missing?

```
    def clean_test():
        conn = None
        try:
            params = config()
            conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT id, title, summary FROM gov_table ORDER BY id")
            print("Records: ", cur.rowcount)
            row = cur.fetchone()

            while row is not None:
                cleaned_row = [i.strip('{}') if type(i) == str else str(i) for i in row]
                title = cleaned_row[1]
                summary = cleaned_row[2]
                id = row[0]
                cur.execute("UPDATE gov_table SET title = %s, summary = %s WHERE id = %s", (title, summary, id))

                row = cur.fetchone()

            cur.close()
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
        finally:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()
```

No records are updated and only one record is pulled and cleaned.

It stops with "no results to fetch".

Comment: You're reusing `cur` to execute the `UPDATE` when you're still expecting to read from it with `.fetchone()` - of course, there's nothing to fetch after the `UPDATE`

Comment: It won't return a list of objects. It may return the number of rows updated.

Comment: I don't know how to fix it. If I delete the update statement, it goes through all the records and cleans them. I just don't know how to write it so that it updates each one.

Answer (score 0):

The following rewrite worked. The big clincher? conn.commit()

```
    def clean_test():
        conn = None
        try:
            params = config()
            conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT id, title, summary FROM gov_table ORDER BY id")
            print("Records: ", cur.rowcount)
            rows = cur.fetchall()

            for row in rows:
                cleaned_row = [i.strip('{}') if type(i) == str else str(i) for i in row]
                title = cleaned_row[1]
                summary = cleaned_row[2]
                id = row[0]
                print(title)
                print(summary)
                print(id)
                cur.execute("UPDATE gov_table SET title = %s, summary = %s WHERE id = %s", (title, summary, id))
                conn.commit()

            cur.close()
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
        finally:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()
```

Hopefully this will help someone else not be so dumb.